# visual studio 2017 .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.0

Tags: visual-studio-2017, .net-core-2.0

I am breaking my head over this for a while now:

I have tried installing both professional and community version of visual studio 2017 v 15.5.2

and installed .net core Runtime 2.0.3 and .net core SDK 2.1.2.

When I open a new web application I get an error saying

> "the sdk 'microsoft.net.sdk.web' specified could not be found"

When I try to build an existing project I get an error

> "the current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.0. Either
>   target .NET Core 1.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that
>   supports .NET Core 2.0."

I don't see `".net core 2.0"` in my target framework

I don't have `global.json` file in my computer

When I try `dotnet --info`, I get this

```
.NET Command Line Tools (2.1.2)
```

> Product Information:
>
> Version:            2.1.2
>
> Commit SHA-1 hash:  5695315371
>
> Runtime Environment:
>
> OS Name:     Windows
>
> OS Version:  10.0.10586
>
> OS Platform: Windows
>
> RID:         win10-x64
>
> Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.2\
>
> Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host
>
> Version  : 2.0.3
>
> Build    : a9190d4a75f4a982ae4b4fa8d1a24526566c69df

Some one please help

Comment: try [2.1.3 SDK with 2.0.4 runtime](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archives/2.0.4-download.md)

Comment: Tried it but no luck :(

Comment: open cmd and run **dotnet --version** and look which version it shows. maybe you still have old 1.x versions installed. remove them

Comment: C:\windows\system32>dotnet --version
2.1.3

Answer (score 3):

Fixed it by adding a MSBuildSdksPath userVariable.

Add an Enviroment variable named `MSBuildSdksPath`.

It's value should point to a Dotnet SDK folder. Eg:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.102\Sdks
```

Comment: I had similar issue when opening a solution in VS2017, which I had been developing in VS2019. In VS2017 I could not see or select Standard 2.0. I reopened the solution in VS2019 and it was broken there too! ....Adding the variable fixed it.